# OpenOffice and MS Office formats conversion into TIFF

Tags: .net, components, file-format

I'm looking for a set of .NET components (or a conversion solution) that allow for converting a source document into a series of raster image (a multi-page TIFF would be the best). Also, they must support working with embedded documents (like documents included in a Word document), at least allowing to retrieve the embedded document for further processing.

File formats that shall be supported:

- DOC and DOCX
- RTF
- XLS and XLSX
- PPT and PPTX
- ODT
- ODS
- ODP

Nice to have:

- PDF
- PDF/A
- HTML (preferably non-IE based rendering — it's going to be used in a server system)
- MSG (dtto)

I've been looking into Aspose's components, that seem to have a solid reputation, but they don't support OpenOffice formats.

I have quite strong requirements for the vendor:

- no one-man shops or open source projects with uncertain future
- should be a commercial offering
- must provide commercial priority support
- must have a compatibility guarantee for future format updates as part of a maintenance subscription

The licensing mode doesn't matter much, need not be royalty free. The intended use is for a single custom development project.

Comment: It's nice to see someone ask a question where they actually *prefer* to pay for software libraries that handle document conversions.  Everyone always seems to want this solution for free so this is a welcome change.

Comment: Thanks Ben :-) I'm kind of reluctant to rely on open source or otherwise free projects for a system that will hold terabytes of data with a lifespan of 10+ years.

Comment: Leadtools can convert from PDF, and can convert to many of the ones you have listed, but I am not sure about the other way around, worth a look thought.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of any out-of-the-box solutions, but one approach may be to print the documents to postscript files and use Ghostscript to convert them to TIFF. I am pretty sure this can be done programmatically for most of the programs you listed (you will probably need different solutions for MS Office and Open Office). For example, here is a VBA snippet we used in MS Powerpoint to print single page to a postscript file using the Ghostscript printer driver:

```
Sub CreatePostscriptfile(filename As String, pageNo As Integer)
    With ActivePresentation.PrintOptions
        .RangeType = ppPrintCurrent
        .NumberOfCopies = 1
        .Collate = msoTrue
        .OutputType = ppPrintOutputSlides
        .PrintHiddenSlides = msoTrue
        .PrintColorType = ppPrintColor
        .FitToPage = msoFalse
        .FrameSlides = msoFalse
        .ActivePrinter = "Ghostscript PDF"
    End With
    ActivePresentation.PrintOut From:=Str$(pageNo ), To:=Str$(pageNo ), _
           PrintToFile:=filename 
End Sub
```

(Using the COM interface of the MS Office applications via .NET looks very much alike to this VBA routine.) I am not used to the OpenOffice API, but I think it should not be too hard to find out how this works in an analogues way.

Comment: Using the Office packages themselves in any kind of an automated interop is not an option for this server-side deployment.

Comment: You can use Open Office's command-line interface from .NET to save as PDF, then use GhostScript to convert to TIFF.

Comment: @Ondrej: I suspect you are going to design some kind of document management / archiving system? If you want to be 100% sure the TIFF will exactly contain what you get when you print your documents to paper, you have to go the "print-to-file" route. AFAIK this can be done without interop, but I hardly believe there's a trustworthy solution without the original Office applications (at least, I never heard of one). Even Open Office has problems to display MS Office documents correctly when it comes to embedded documents.